# Permission Denied when trying to change to Kibana directory

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos, kibana, elastic-stack, amazon-linux-2

I am in the process of configuring an ELK Stack in an EC2 instance, which runs on Amazon Linux 2 OS(CentOS). As the third step, I have just installed Kibana in my remote machine . According to [this tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html) on Elastic.co , I have to modify a file named kibana.yml in order to unlock its full functionality. The file is said to be located in /etc/kibana directory. The directory already exists. However, I **cannot cd to the Kibana directory**. For the normal cd command, I get the error

> -bash: cd: /etc/kibana/: Permission denied

When I use the same command with *sudo prefix*, I do not get any error, however, *it doesn't change to the directory either.*

Any idea on how to bypass this and enter the directory?

P.S : I am not sure if this is an issue specific to Kibana or not. However, this is the first time I have encountered an issue like this in a CentOS system.

Comment: Why do you need to cd to the directory? Just run sudo ls /etc/kibana etc?

Comment: @RamanSailopal I have to edit the kibana.yml file inside that Kibana directory.

Comment: So run sudo nano /etc/kibana/kibana.yml or sudo vi /etc/kibana/kibana.yml.

Comment: Thanks! The "sudo vi etc/kibana/kibana.yml" worked. Btw, any idea why the system won't permit to sudo into the directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to bypass this, although I am still not clear why the *Permission Denied* error appears. But since I got the solution to my issue, I am posting this as the answer.

1. @Raman's answer : Editing the file using sudo and giving the full address to the file, *without* changing the directory.

   sudo vi /etc/kibana/kibana.yml
2. My answer : Enter the Root mode using `sudo su` command and that would allow you to change to the kibana directory.